# See which user deleted files when viewing deleted files on dropbox.com

Tags: dropbox

I've got a Dropbox folder shared with a team. Someone recently deleted all of the children folders by accident, its not an issue as we can restore them back from dropbox.com using their web interface as Dropbox keeps a copy of deleted files for 30 days (indefinitely if you have the packrat add on).

What I want to find is which team member deleted the files, so I can point it out to them so they don't do it again I future, any idea where I can find who deleted the files ?

Answer (score 2):

It should say in the Events feed for that folder which computer or account they were deleted from.